# How do I recover Joplin notes if they were never exported?

Tags: live-usb, snap, data-recovery

I have an old Ubuntu machine that no longer works, but I can still access its drive through a live USB. None of the notes were ever exported; though, I was expecting to recover them by some other means. How do I do this? I see the Joplin app folder/files and that it was installed on the machine via snap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are stored in an SQLite database. Default location (normal and [snap](https://github.com/MrCarroll/joplin-desktop-snap)):

```
~/.config/joplin-desktop/database.sqlite
~/snap/joplin-desktop/current/.config/joplin-desktop
```

Find the one you are after on your system and then from command line you can do ...

```
sqlite3 ~/.config/joplin-desktop/database.sqlite
sqlite3 ~/snap/joplin-desktop/current/.config/joplin-desktop
```

and then use the SQL language to view and dump data from it.  `.help` will show available options.

Comment: Note that location of the snap application will be different, somewhere under ~/snap

Comment: @vanadium yeah found it online just now.

Comment: An easier and more powerful way to access data is with `sqlitebrowser`.

Comment: yep, that's one of my most upvoted answers

Comment: Or copy the `.sqlite` file to a current system which can access the information. Unlike some more traditional databases, the `.sqlite` is all you need to read/transfer an SQLite database.